# How to setup reporting for a change management request system?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I setup a change management request system in our SharePoint Online environment following the directions from this link

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19797.sharepoint-2013-build-a-change-management-request-without-code.aspx?PageIndex=2

And I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to have any kind of reporting to be able to sift through let's say a month's worth of requests. Is there a database we can query?

Comment: The "database" would be the list the users are submitting change requests to. You would need list views set up to show the desired data.

Comment: How would I go about doing that Eric? Do you have a link that I could reference?

Comment: Something like this: http://en.share-gate.com/blog/what-is-a-sharepoint-view-and-how-to-use-it? There is also the possibility of using the REST APIs and passing data into your favorite JS Charting tools to generate charts and graphs. I don't know how deep or custom you are wanting to go.

Comment: Basically were just wanting a log of the requests so there's a backup copy somewhere else besides on the SharePoint team site. It doesn't need to be elaborate with a bunch of charts and graphs.

Comment: You could always just create a view with the necessary data, and connect to Excel where you could view it and create pivot charts and stuff.

Comment: I tried connecting to Excel and most of it looked ok but some of the fields instead of showing the text displayed a really long path instead. I used the data from the OData Data feed straight from the url of the team site and added all three lists. So I wasn't sure why some fields weren't displaying correctly while others were.